# Hyperlinking Google Map directions in AGOL arcade popup without losing DDMMSS N|S formatting

Tags: arcgis-online, google-maps, arcade, html-popup

How do I hyperlink Google Map directions in AGOL arcade popup without losing DDMMSS N|S formatting?

The link works correctly in ArcGIS Pro and goes to the centroid of the feature polygon.

Example: [https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=**40°](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=**40%C2%B0) 21' 50.57058587" N,078° 06' 05.58313988" W** (40°21'50.6"N 78°06'05.6"W)

When this url is added as a hyperlink for text, the formatting drops off giving me:

[https://www.google.com/maps/place/**4%C2%B000'00.0%22N+0%C2%B021'50.6%22E**/@3.7346393,-3.5470476,5.92z/data=!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d4!4d0.3640474?entry=ttu](https://www.google.com/maps/place/**4%C2%B000%2700.0%22N+0%C2%B021%2750.6%22E**/@3.7346393,-3.5470476,5.92z/data=!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d4!4d0.3640474?entry=ttu)

essentially dropping most formatting and leaving me in the Gulf of Guinea (4°00'00.0"N 0°21'50.6"E).

Comment: I'm surprised your example even works, I though spaces in URL's were forbidden. I would look at firing off decimal degrees to the [map api](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Could you please attach the arcade function that is producing the link for you?